# Jenkinsfile - Conditional stage execution in the Script Pipeline syntax

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

We are using the **Script Pipeline** syntax for our `Jenkinsfile` which has a lot of stage defined to build and deploy our code. We have a use case where I want to run all my stages if I am doing a ***Full Build*** but only run one specific stage if I need to perform some AWS routing. I know I can use the `if(<expression>)` to skip a stage or run a stage. Problem is I don't want to apply that `if` condition to every stage in my `Jenkinsfile`.

In the new **Declarative Pipeline** syntax this is easily possible using the `stage..when` option. We have a lot of custom Groovy helper function used in our infrastructure so it is not possible at this point for me to switch from the **Script Pipeline** syntax to the new **Declarative Pipeline** syntax. What I ended up doing on my existing `Jenkinsfile` is something like this..

Original Jenkinsfile

```
  stage('Checkout Code') {}
  stage('Build') {}
  parallel(
    stage('Sonar Analysis') {}
    stage('CLM Analysis') {}
    stage('Security Analysis') {}
  )
  stage('Build Docker Image') {}
  ...
  ...
  stage('QA Deploy') {}
  stage('QA Routing') {}
  ...
  ...
  stage('Prod Deploy') {}
  stage('Prod Routing') {}
```

Changed to

```
  if (fullDeploy){
    stage('Full Build') {
        stage('Checkout Code') {}
        stage('Build') {}
        parallel(
          stage('Sonar Analysis') {}
          stage('CLM Analysis') {}
          stage('Security Analysis') {}
        )
        stage('Build Docker Image') {}
        ...
        ...
        stage('QA Deploy') {}
        stage('QA Routing') {}
        ...
        ...
        stage('Prod Deploy') {}
        stage('Prod Routing') {}          
    }
  }

  if (routeOnly){
    stage('Prod Routing') {}    
  }
```

This feels a little hacky to me and I couldn't find any things on the Jenkins docs that provides a good way to do this.

Has anyone got a better way in which I can incorporate this?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way in scripted pipelines to skip stages - see [JENKINS-37781](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37781).

Comment: Thanks @mkobit. This is helpful to know.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I also disliked the idea of having a redundant **if{}** block inside my **stage{}**.
I solved this by overwriting the stage as follows

```
def stage(name, execute, block) {
    return stage(name, execute ? block : {echo "skipped stage $name"})
}
```

now you can disable a stage as follows

```
stage('Full Build', false) { 
    ...
}
```

**Update**
You could also mark stage skipped using below def

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

def stage(name, execute, block) {
    return stage(name, execute ? block : {
        echo "skipped stage $name"
        Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Really nice idea!

Comment: Didn't work for me... I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [Verification Pre-prod, true]" on stage("Verify ${stageToDisplay}", overallBuildRun)  for a parallel execution

Comment: @DeanChen did you get the same way for a parallel(stages) scripted way? I can't get it

Comment: @Marcello de Sales I did not use parallel for this.

Comment: hi, I use scripted stage to have dynamic parallel stages. Because of scripted when is not possible, but I want to see all possible stages and want to see execution or not. The mentioned  Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME) is working fine only for the overview, skipped stage is now empty, but in the blue ocean view the skipped stages also have a checkmark. Anyone has this,too?

Answer (score 4):

Per the comments on [JENKINS-47286](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47286), it doesn't sound like adding `when` support to Scripted Pipeline will happen. As a potential workaround, there is a shared library implementing the `when` statement for scripted pipelines: https://github.com/comquent/imperative-when

Answer (score 3):

I don't use scripted pipelines, but I'm pretty sure that's the way you'd do it (enclosing the conditional stages in an `if`).

If you want it to act a bit more like declarative, you could put `if` statements inside each stage instead. That way the stages would still be visualized. This may or may not be desirable when they didn't actually do anything.

I think switching to declarative will be the only way to get the skipped stages displayed differently in the blue ocean UI (they look different when they are skipped due to a `when` clause), but you actually have the smallest code with your current solution. It doesn't seem hacky to me, but that sort of thing can be subjective. :)

Comment: Thanks @burnettk. You are right. This is very subjective. I will leave this question open for a bit in case someone comes along and gives me a nice and elegant way to do this. If not I will accept your response as an answer.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, there is a way to do it in scripted pipeline. It is quite easy once you find the good source: [comquent.de](https://comquent.de/en/skipped-stages-in-jenkins-scripted-pipeline/)

Answer (score 1):

*(Built on top of culmat's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784839/9993205)*

Below provides 2 choices:

1. mark stage as skipped, but still **show** in UI,
2. or completely skip stage - **hide** in UI

`vars/stageConditional.groovy`:

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.Utils

def skipped(name, execute, block){
    log.HEADER "STAGE: $name"
    return stage(name, execute ? block : {
        echo "Skipped (shown in UI) stage $name"
        Utils.markStageSkippedForConditional(STAGE_NAME)
    })
}
def hidden(name, execute, block) {
    log.HEADER "STAGE: $name"
    if (execute){
        return stage(name, block)
    } else {
        echo "Hidden (not shown in UI) stage $name"
    }
}
```

**Usage**: it is a drop-in replacements for a `stage`, with condition added.

**Example**: unless `dockerize` is `true`, both stages are hidden (note: stage is inside stage). Otherwise build, but publish conditionally (e.g. not in bugfix/feature branch), marking stage as skipped.

```
        stageConditional.hidden('Java: build Docker image', plan.docker.dockerize) {
          gradlew('buildImage')

          stageConditional.skipped('Java: push Docker image', plan.publish.publish) {
            gradlew('pushImage')
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use environmental variables for skipping stages.

```
stage("Release"){
    steps{
        // Release procedure
    }
    when {
        allOf{
            branch 'release'
            not{
                environment name: 'JENKINS_SKIP_RELEASE', value: 'TRUE'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my specific way of working the whole pipeline is a [variable in a shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) So I tweaked it to check for an specific variable.

```
def call(body) {

    // Execute the body and get parameters back.
    def params = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = params
    body()

    if (params.skip_release){
        env.JENKINS_SKIP_RELEASE = 'TRUE'
    }

[...]
```

Then all my `Jenkinsfile` looks like a bunch of parameters.

```
@Library('shared') _

myGeneralizedPipeline {
    skip_release = true
    //Other parameters comes in this body
}
```

Comment: You provided an example of the declarative when directive.  This doesn't answer the OP's question.  They want to know how to implement something similar for scripted pipeline.  They already know how to do a when directive for declarative.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification but the score of my answer speaks for itself in this regard.